# Why is my ndarray crossing the maximum supported dimension while it originally contains 70000 instances?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I read the MNIST dataset and put the labels inside the y-variable.
It's a ndarray object containing 70000 instances of labels and its shape is (70000,)
Now, I wish to convert the labels to float64, but my interpreter tells
"maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 70000".

So I don't understand why it originally contains 70000 instances as an ndarray object without any problem and than reports this error when trying to convert the internal datatype.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    print(type(y))
    print(y.shape)
    y = np.ndarray(y,dtype=np.float64)
    print(X.dtype,y.dtype)
    data = pd.DataFrame()


Output:
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(70000,)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-5d7ca8b0f5a9> in <module>
      3 print(type(y))
      4 print(y.shape)
----> 5 y = np.ndarray(y,dtype=np.float64)
      6 print(X.dtype,y.dtype)
      7 data = pd.DataFrame()

ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 70000
```

Comment: Use `numpy.array` instead of `numpy.ndarray`.  `ndarray` is actually a relatively low-level object.   Its first argument is the *shape* of the array to be created, not the data to put in the array.  You are passing in `y`, which has length 70000, so `ndarray` interprets that as an attempt to create an array with 70000 dimensions.

Comment: Also, if what you want is simply to change the type of `y`, you can simply do `y = y.astype(np.float64)` (may pass `copy=False` if you want to avoid making a copy in the case `y` has already type `np.float64`).

Comment: What are these `labels` objects?  Does `float(y[0])` work?  If `y` is already a numpy array there are correct methods for converting the `dtype` - within limits.   `np.ndarray` is advanced feature that you shouldn't use (especially without reading its docs carefully).

Comment: You weren't the only one mistakenly using `ndarray` today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661651/cannot-understand-the-output-of-this-code-python-list-to-1-d-numpy-array