# Cannot understand the output of this code: python list to 1-d numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I tried to create turn a python list into a numpy array, but got very unintuitive output. Certainly I did something wrong, but out of curiosity I would like to know why I got such an output.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

# Exercise 2
a = [1, 5, 3, 6, 2]
b = np.ndarray(a)
print(b, b.dtype)
```

the output was

```
[[[[[0.00000000e+000 6.93284651e-310]
    [6.93284792e-310 6.93284744e-310]
    [6.93284744e-310 6.93284744e-310]
    [6.93284744e-310 6.93284744e-310]
    [6.93284744e-310 6.93284744e-310]
    [6.93284744e-310 6.93284744e-310]]

   [[6.93284744e-310 2.20882835e-314]
    [6.93284743e-310 6.93284743e-310]
    [6.93284743e-310 6.93284650e-310]
    [6.93284744e-310 6.93284744e-310]
    [6.93284744e-310 6.93284744e-310]
    [6.93284744e-310 6.93284744e-310]]

   ... (12 more blocks similar to ones above)

   [[6.93284871e-310 6.93284871e-310]
    [6.93284745e-310 6.93284871e-310]
    [6.93284651e-310 6.93284871e-310]
    [6.93284745e-310 6.93284871e-310]
    [6.93284871e-310 6.93284745e-310]
    [6.93284727e-310 6.93284871e-310]]]]] float64
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ndarray and array in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879315/what-is-the-difference-between-ndarray-and-array-in-numpy)

Comment: Trenton, not exactly, but thank you for the reference. I spotted my mistake, just want to understand why I got this particular output. From the answers I got why the output is of this shape, but now I am also curious about the values.

Comment: Probably floating point precision. They are all equivalently 0

Comment: With `ndarray` you did not specify the `buffer`, just the `shape`.  So those values are 'uninitialized', not even to 0.  Use `np.zeros(shape)` if you want an array of 0s with a given shape.

Comment: [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a five dimensional array.

```
a = [1, 5, 3, 6, 2]
b = np.ndarray(a)
print(b.shape)
```

gives

```
(1, 5, 3, 6, 2)
```

The first argument of the `np.ndarray` is the shape of the array.
Your probably wanted

```
b = np.array(a)
print(b)
```

which gives

```
[1 5 3 6 2]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the clearest answer. Can you also tell me why the most values are 6*10^(-310), while some of them are different?

Comment: I think it is an empty array, so it is whatever was in memory at the spot that the array was created. Try it again and you'll likely get different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a n-dimensional array whereby n = 5 which is the length of the array passed (which form the dimensions as explained [here](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)).

It's likely you're looking for:

```py
np.array(a)
```

Those numbers are float 0.

Answer (score 1):

To create an array from a list, use: `b = np.array(a)`.
`np.ndarray` is another numpy class, and the first argument of the function is the shape of the array (hence the shape of your array being `b.shape -> (1, 5, 3, 6, 2)`)

Answer (score 0):

`np.ndarray(shape, dtype=float....)` the argument require shape, so it will create a new array with shape (1, 5, 3, 6, 2) in your example

```
a = [1, 5, 3, 6, 2]
b = np.ndarray(a)
print(b.shape)
```

return

```
(1, 5, 3, 6, 2)
```

what you want is `np.array`

```
a = [1, 5, 3, 6, 2]
b = np.array(a)
print(b.shape)
```

return

```
(5,)
```